# Understing loops with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

In node js i have a function that iterates trough an array to fill another element. Some times some proprerties are undefined, how can that be? For example i get "cannot read property formattedPrice of undefined". What is wrong with a for loop on node?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(item.SmallImage));
        message.attachment.payload.elements[i] = {
            "title":items[i].ItemAttributes.Title,
            "image_url": items[i].LargeImage.URL,
            "subtitle":items[i].ItemAttributes.ListPrice.FormattedPrice,
            "default_action": {
            "type": "web_url",
            "url": "https://www.google.it",
            "messenger_extensions": true,
            "webview_height_ratio": "tall",
            "fallback_url": "https://www.google.it"
            },
            "buttons":[
                {
                  "type":"web_url",
                  "url":"https://www.google.it",
                  "title":"View Website"
              },{
                  "type":"postback",
                  "title":"Start Chatting",
                  "payload":"DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
              }             
          ]      
        }
    //sendMessage( senderId, {text: item.ItemAttributes.Title+" PREZZO**:"+item.ItemAttributes.ListPrice.FormattedPrice});
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else. Most likely you're running into trouble with the asynchronous nature of Javascript. You should show how `items` is populated. otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: It's just telling you that some of your `items` have `item.ItemAttributes.ListPrice` that is `undefinied`

Answer (score 1):

`cannot read property formattedPrice of undefined` means the object from which you were trying to access formattedPrice, `items[i].ItemAttributes.ListPrice`, is null/undefined.

To prevent that error from occurring, you should include some validation before assigning the value to `message.attachment.payload.elements[i]`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var subtitle = "N/A";
    if (items[i].ItemAttributes.ListPrice == null) {
        subtitle = items[i].ItemAttributes.ListPrice.FormattedPrice;
    }
    message.attachment.payload.elements[i] = {
        ...
        "subtitle": subtitle, // will now show as "N/A" instead of causing program to crash
        ...
    };
}
```

Another thing to consider is that in the for loop, instead of having the condition as `i < 10`, replace it with `i < items.length`, unless you are sure the items list will always contain 10 or more elements.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the problem is something with async because that objects has those properties set for sure but they are sometimes undefined like they are still not been assigned

Comment: @PjotrRaskolnikov can you update the question to include where/how you are using async?